# Dos2unix on Java files

Tags: java, linux, ant, dos2unix

Are there any impacts or repercussions if the dos2unix command is run on Java source files, right before they are compiled? The Java files would be downloaded from a CVS repository in Linux and then compiled to a jar by an Ant script. Thanks.

Comment: My god, a CVS repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to even test this (theoretically): in the Java languages, line breaks bare no semantical meaning. Therefore there presence is irrelevant (to the compiler that is).

So a human reader mind find it very unpleasant to look at source code that has *zero* newlines, or a newline in just any place where they are legit - for the compiler, as said: it doesn't matter.

Therefore tools like dos2unix are not supposed to make any changes to source code that could make a "semantical" difference.

And of course: the real answer is: don't spend your time worrying about line breaks. Invest it into moving your the whole system from 1999 to 2018 (by getting replacing say CVS with git, and Ant with maven/gradle for example).

Comment: Well newlines certainly have _some_ meaning, since they count as token-separating whitespace. E.g., `a\nb` is two separate tokens, a and b while `ab` is one token, ab. That said, as it pertains to the question your point stands I think - that exception doesn't invalidate transforming newlines (but removing them may be dangerous).

Answer (score 0):

No. All it does is deal with line endings.

Answer (score 0):

## Practical test

First I created a test file with Linux line endings called `Main.java`, unsurprisingly on Linux this compiled.

```
0x63 [ c]  0x6c [ l]  0x61 [ a]  0x73 [ s]  0x73 [ s]  
0x20 [  ]  0x4d [ M]  0x61 [ a]  0x69 [ i]  0x6e [ n]  
0x20 [  ]  0x7b [ {]  0x0a [\n]  0x7d [ }]  0x0a [\n]  
0x0a [\n]
```

Converting to DOS endings gave this:

```
0x63 [ c]  0x6c [ l]  0x61 [ a]  0x73 [ s]  0x73 [ s]  
0x20 [  ]  0x4d [ M]  0x61 [ a]  0x69 [ i]  0x6e [ n]  
0x20 [  ]  0x7b [ {]  0x0d [\r]  0x0a [\n]  0x7d [ }]  
0x0d [\r]  0x0a [\n]  0x0d [\r]  0x0a [\n]
```

Which still compiles, and converting back gives:

```
0x63 [ c]  0x6c [ l]  0x61 [ a]  0x73 [ s]  0x73 [ s]  
0x20 [  ]  0x4d [ M]  0x61 [ a]  0x69 [ i]  0x6e [ n]  
0x20 [  ]  0x7b [ {]  0x0a [\n]  0x7d [ }]  0x0a [\n]  
0x0a [\n]
```

Which is the same as before

## Line endings

The difference between the Windows (dos) and Linux / Mac (unix) line endings is that the line ending on unix is `\n` whereas the line ending on dos is `\r\n`.

## Results

- As the unix2dos / dos2unix only changes line endings it does not change the contents
- At least on Linux, javac can compile source files with either line ending successfully.